# How to write linear model with fixed and random effect

Tags: r, lm, lme4

I'm trying to figure out if I'm writing my linear mixed effect model in the correct manner to compare the models.

The experimental set up:

We are looking at the length~weight relationship of a species of snails. We chose 3 sites (rivers) for these experiments that we consider a fixed effect- we expect there to be a difference, we just want to see the magnitude of that difference between rivers. We also have the snails in different individual groups (6 groups/river) so that we could keep them in a constant area to be measured. We don't expect/aren't interested in a group effect, but want to make sure it isn't causing any issues. So here we want to see the effect of the river on the length~weight relationship with cage as a source of random effects.

I have written the models as follows to compare with AIC:

No group effect:

```
Model1<-aov(Weight~Length*River,data=SnailData)
```

Group effect:

```
Model2<-lmer(Weight~Length*River +(1|group),data=SnailData)
```

Would this be correct, or is there a different way I should be looking at the group random effect?

Comment: That should work assuming your `group` variable is coded uniquely (that is, group IDs are not repeated in different rivers, unless the snails are also repeated.).

Comment: Thanks!. That is correct, each `group` has it's own code, none are repeated.

Comment: For advice about statistical modeling, you should instead ask at [stats.se]. How you "should" be looking at your data really isn't a programming question.